What happens to people who fall from their Jati and Varna?
Do they become Avarna or the same as Shudras? What all is a Fallen person not allowed to do and what were the Hindus who never fell supposed to do with people who fell?
I remember someone on Hindu Stack Exchange saying fallen people do not become Avarna but fallen Dwijas become the same as Shudras and they also said the only thing that could make someone Avarna was having kids born of mixed Varnas
But I also remember reading from the Manusmriti that eating onions and garlic could make someone a Outcaste
But could it be that becoming Outcasted by everyone else could be just one of the Punishments for falling from a Varna even if they do become the same as Shudras and not Avarna?
Someone please explain
